# Problem with armature

Tags: armature, bones

hi everyone i am new to blender i have a problem, i have created hand bones for the downloaded model, when i move the bone in pose mode the hand is cut off from the model. I set my own weight for the bone, but it didn't help.
P.s  I am attaching a video to make it clearer.

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12FCegj3w3mrJ_mLLXvW-D_eXBEkWPdFO/view?usp=sharing

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tJ6AlxctD3ItR9CToQ-CIreJjnVTRtmP/view?usp=sharing

3d model:
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/pubg-character-outfit-03dbcfbffa6c42c9a622970d643ebcd5

[image]

Comment: Your mesh is split into multiple pieces-- there are duplicate verts, and those duplicates don't have identical weights with each other.  The easiest fix on your file is to select a healthy chunk of the arm+shoulder vertices in edit mode and merge by distance.

Comment: Thank you so much!